# Concatenate URL in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I need to concatenate "/images/" with `s:url value=${Friend.PhotoAdd}` so it should be /images/value of Friend.PhotoAdd

Comment: have you tried adding namespace like `<s:url value="${Friend.PhotoAdd}" namespace="images"/>`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I added                                                                       <div id="Photo"><img src="<s:url value="${Friend.PhotoAdd}" namespace="images"/>"/></div>                                      but got this error According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Comment: that is because of the `<img src>` tag

Comment: Does your JSP configuration not allow EL expressions?

Comment: what is `Friend` and what is `PhotoAdd`

Comment: Friend is a variable <c:forEach var="Friend" items="${FriendsList}"> , it accept EL expressions but I am wondering whats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `<s:url value="image${Friend.PhotoAdd}"/>`?